# How to make the default intent of choosing image from gallery but within the `RecyclerView.Adapter`

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm stucked in very strange situation. As `onActivityResult()` method is used to get the image after choosing image from the gallery, but this method can't be used inside the RecyclerView Adapter like `MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>{...}`

So how I implement `onActivityResult()` inside this adapter? because its the only way to get the image and I have the `onClickListener` inside the adapter's `ViewHolder`

Comment: create interface in adapter class, access that interface in your activity, and access the method of your interface by passing some values like (getAdapterPosition()), then from there you can call onActivityResult in that activity

Comment: Please show me the code so I can understand it little bit more.